Organizing Content within an AI Search Index
I have thousands of text based content pages. I want to index them organized into categories within Microsoft's AI search Indexes. Any reccommendations/best practices?
I am thinking adding metatags but not sure if this is the best approach

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add what have you tried so far.
